# Docker rootless Error: you need to share your Docker host socket with a volume at /var/run/docker.sock

Tags: docker, rootless, letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

I am trying to go rootless with Docker.

I have followed all the steps presented in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless). I also allowed the use of the unprivileged ports, to include the 443.

To test if everything works the way I need it, I installed the ["nginx-proxy-automation"](https://github.com/evertramos/nginx-proxy-automation).

Everything got installed flawlessly. **However**, the `jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:2.1` container

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx-proxy-automation-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:${NGINX_PROXY_COMPANION_IMAGE_VERSION:-2.0}
    container_name: ${LETS_ENCRYPT_SEVICE_NAME:-nginx-proxy-automation-letsencrypt}
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ${NGINX_FILES_PATH:-./data}/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ${NGINX_FILES_PATH:-./data}/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ${NGINX_FILES_PATH:-./data}/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ${NGINX_FILES_PATH:-./data}/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - ${NGINX_FILES_PATH:-./data}/acme.sh:/etc/acme.sh
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

reports the following error:

```
Error: you need to share your Docker host socket with a volume at /var/run/docker.sock
Typically you should run your container with: '-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro' 
Info: running acme-companion version v2.1.0
```

which causes the container to restart every *x* seconds.

What can I do to fix it? What am I missing?

## Workaround

Based on @gdahlm 's answer, I first tried the following:

```
- unix://$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

But I got the following error:

> ERROR: Volume unix://$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
> has incorrect format, should be external:internal[:mode]

simply because there's an extra `:` colon in the volume path.

So digging further in this [Trying Rootless Docker with Testcontainers](https://bsideup.github.io/posts/rootless_docker/) article, I then tried

```
- $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

But it didn't work either, because I got the following error:

> ERROR: Named volume "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
> is used in service "docker-gen-auto" but no declaration was found in
> the volumes section.

Finally I tried echoing out the `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` in the terminal, like so:

```
$ echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
```

And I got:

`/run/user/1000`

So, I hardcoded it into the `.env` file variable:

`DOCKER_HOST_ROOTLESS_PATH=/run/user/1000/docker.sock`

and inside the `docker-compose.yml` file

```
  - ${DOCKER_HOST_ROOTLESS_PATH:-/var/run/docker.sock}:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
```

**And it finally worked!**

But leaving it like this inside the `.env` file:

`DOCKER_HOST_ROOTLESS_PATH=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/docker.sock`

didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a `jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion` specific bug, if you look in the `docker-compose.yml` you will see this.

```
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
```

Try changing that to:

```
   - "unix://$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
```

But that value may change based on how your install is configured.

Really the maintainer of `jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion` needs to move to using `$DOCKER_HOST` vs using a hard coded path.

Comment: Thank you so much. However, now I'm facing a new problem with this path `Volume unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro has incorrect format, should be external:internal[:mode]` due to the extra `:` colon right after the `UNIX` word, as also [expressed here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7909). Any ideas to overcome that?

Comment: Nevermind. Your answer helped me find a workaround anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it for those running Docker on Windows with WSL, try running `docker compose up -d` using WSL instead of PowerShell.

From the accepted answer, since the dev used a hardcoded path instead of `$DOCKER_HOST` most likely the difference in the file systems causes the error so of course when you specify `"unix://$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/...` it works, but ultimately it is up to the maintainers to tackle this as gdahlm also stated in his answer.